# Is it possible to uninstall Ubuntu and let only Windows installed?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, windows-7

I bought a computer and asked the seller to install a pirated version of Windows 7 on its 250GB SSD. However, it came with only 80GB of free space on it with no heavy softwares installed, as there is both Ubuntu and Windows installed, which is very few for my needs. 
In the OS selection screen (GNU GRUB - version 2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.1) , it has Ubuntu and Windows 7 (loader). Ubuntu seems to consume 114GB in the disk space, and as I only use Windows, is there a way to remove Ubuntu and let only Windows on it?

Comment: buy a hard disk and have both

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all Ubuntu is defnitely better then Windows nowadays. I'm requesting that you try Ubuntu first.

Now to the question. It is very much possible to remove 1 OS from dual boot. I have my own easy way to do it.

**Step 1:** Boot from windows booted pendrive/windows CD-DVD.

**Step 2:** On the screen you will have a giant button called ***install now***. Below this u will find a option '***repair your pc***'. Click on that.

**Step 3:** Now on troubleshooting, click on advanced then command prompt.

**Note**: here, I need to clear something. There are many way to go to command prompt. Like, from windows hold shift and click on restart. This also take you to troubleshooting options. If you have your windows running this will be a better idea.

**Step 4:** Now, Run these:

```
bootrec /fixmbr
bootrec /fixboot
```

**Step 5:** Restart PC. Now u wont see any boot option. after open the PC delete those partitions contained **Ubuntu**.

Comment: Thanks, but I only needed to use a program called EasyBCD to delete Ubuntu partitions and expand Windows' ones.

Comment: welcome. On my case, EasyBCD did not perform well. That's why I didn't mansion it earlier.